# Notify (via SNS or otherwise ) if copy fails on redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have cronjobs setup which copies data into redshift from s3 using copy command. I want a notification to be sent whenever copy fails. Could find "Amazon Redshift Events" but they are at cluster level; not at copy command level.

Any help please !

Comment: Can't you just capture the return value of the copy command and trigger an SNS message if it isn't a success?

Comment: I agree.. that could be one of the solution but for that my java program need to use aws java sdk.. I thought that anyway console has the status as ABORTED ; so if I can directly configure on AWS ; that would have been easier